# Which Grails version is more compatible with current plugins list?

Tags: grails

I'm trying with the 2.5.0 release of Grails but I have had problems of compatibility with some plugins I've tried (for example searchable)

Which version of Grails you recommend to start a new project? I'd like to start with the version more compatible with the list of current Grails plugins https://grails.org/plugins/

I'm not interested with the newer version but with the most compatible/stable with the current plugins list.

Comment: 2.4.x should be the most stable branch when it comes to plugins. However, keep in mind some plugins aren't being maintained any longer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Both 2.4.x and 2.5.x will work fine with the current plugins in general.

Without any details it's hard to know why the searchable plugin isn't working for you, but note that it only works with Hibernate 3 and the default in new Grails apps is to use Hibernate 4. But you can see that the Hibernate 3 configuration settings are commented out in BuildConfig.groovy and DataSource.groovy so you can easily change back to Hibernate 3.

Having said that, don't use searchable. The underlying Compass library is no longer maintained, and using the searchable plugin will cause scaling problems because it's very inconvenient to get it to use a shared index between servers. The author of Compass created Elasticsearch, and that's a much better option. There's also an [actively maintained plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what about the jquery-ui plugin http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui? In its documentation says that it uses resources framework but I understand that the version 2.5.x replaces it with asset pipeline plugin, there is any incompatibility between the two? Is it compatible jquery-ui plugin with 2.5.x?

Comment: It has built-in support for the resources plugin (i.e. it has the `JqueryUiPluginResources.groovy` file which defines grouped resources) but it will work with both resources and asset-pipeline. You might need to (or want to) make some minor path adjustments when using asset-pipeline.